# Add a vxlan interface to a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I need to configure a vxlan interface on a docker container that runs our router service. Is it possible to add an interface to a docker container? This is based on the alpine container.

Answer (score -1):

You can't add an interface to a docker container. It doesn't have virtualized hardware like a VM. You can however add an interface to the host from within the docker container if you have host networking enabled when building the container. You will then be able to use that interface from within the container.

Not you'll need to add the net capabilities to the container when you build it in order to create an interface.

Comment: the drama is that - you can. container is your real PC, but in custom namespace.